# Find the WAN address range

Tags: ip, isp, wide-area-network, networking

I'm trying to find the WAN IP range for a network on another location.
When I do a tracert on the LAN gw, the last hop is the adress is 79.161.2.255, This is the ip range belonging to the ISP, but I didn't think a Wan adress would end With 255?

I know tracert will not allways find show the WAN IP. I'm not on this network, so I can not take a html request. Is there somthing else I can do to check?

Owner Full IP Range:  79.160.0.0 - 79.161.255.255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an IP address of an Internet host can end in .255, though it's rather uncommon. It would require the subnet to be at least /23.

See [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/q/49765/126632) for the full explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Given the IP address range 79.160.0.0/15 (79.160.0.0 - 79.161.255.255), there is no reason why a host could not have the address 79.161.2.255.